# How to make top align in cfspreadsheet after merge cell using ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I'm making a cell top align, after a merge cell by using spreadsheet functions. What I found on google and [CFML Reference Adobe ColdFusion 10](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category.html) was only 
`left` *(default)*, `right`, `center`, `justify`, `general`, `fill`, and `center_selection`. Is there  any other way or idea that can make it "top align" after merge cell? Here is my code :

```
<cfscript> 
    theSheet = SpreadsheetNew("Order Details 1");
    SpreadsheetAddRow(theSheet, "NO, ,VENDOR, PART NUMBER, PART NAME, PSI, LEAD TIME,MONTH, YEAR, ,N-5, N-4, N-3, 
    N-2, N-1, N, N+1, N+2, N+3, N+4, PACKING MONTH, PRODUCTION MONTH ",5,1); 
    myFormat2=StructNew();
    myFormat2.bold=false;
    myFormat2=StructNew();
    myFormat2.bold=false;
    myFormat2.alignment="vertical_top";
    SpreadsheetFormatRow(theSheet,myFormat2,6);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,6,25,2,2);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,6,25,3,3);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,6,25,4,4);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,6,25,5,5);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,6,25,7,7);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,26,45,2,2);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,26,45,3,3);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,26,45,4,4);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,26,45,5,5);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(theSheet,26,45,7,7);
    SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,getROW);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Im using CF10

Comment: @SySyBy - What's the exact version? `writeDump(server.coldfusion);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `verticalalignment` instead/along with `alignment` for aligning to top. You can use `vertical_top, vertical_bottom, vertical_center, vertical_justifyFor` for different alignments.

For more information go [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html).

```
SpreadsheetFormatCellRange(theSheet,{verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 3,4,30,10);
```

Comment: Have tried it but it does not work and it gives a blank space on top of the cell.

Comment: Are you sure you used `verticalalignment` and not `alignment`?

Comment: Any difference when you use this? `spreadsheetFormatCell(theSheet, {verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 6, 3)`

Comment: Yes im used verticalalignment like this SpreadsheetFormatCellRange (theSheet, {verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 6, 2, 25, 2); but its not work.when I used spreadsheetFormatCell(theSheet, {verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 6, 3) it move to other merge cell below and its still bottom align.

Comment: What's your exact version? Seems to work on trycf.com (10,0,16,293499) to top align column B https://trycf.com/gist/f42d6c97b71ee02123216c23abe4915c/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax Im using ColdFusion Server Enterprise 10,0,23,302580.  When I use this code SpreadsheetFormatCellRange (theSheet, {verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 6, 2, 25, 2); , yes it will make the column B top align but the data inside row 6 will move to row 26 not start at row 6.

Comment: @RRK I try again using  SpreadsheetFormatCellRange (theSheet, {verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"}, 6, 2, 25, 2); and its work!! This is because before this i write SpreadsheetFormatCellRange before SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,getROW);.It should be write like this: SpreadsheetAddRows(theSheet,getROW);
SpreadsheetFormatCellRange (theSheet,{verticalalignment="VERTICAL_TOP"},  6, 2, 25, 2);. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is something you need to keep in mind. I am not sure why but formatting gets overwritten when we add data to a cell.

Comment: Good point about the different settings. `alignment` should really be called "horizontalAlignment".

Answer (score 0):

RRK answer should work but if you are looking for another option there is a plug-in that I have been using for a long time because of the limitations and frustrations of cfspreadsheet.

https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-spreadsheet

I know its is really for Lucee (which I like better than Adobes version) but it does work in Adobe's CF2016 if you end up upgrading which you should be planning since ColdFusion 11 is hitting it's end of life this year.

https://helpx.adobe.com/support/programs/eol-matrix.html